# Number theory involving sum of digits of a number:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let a fixed natural number m be given  Call a positive integer n to be a GRT number iff:

1. $n \equiv 1 \pmod m$
2. Sum of digits in decimal representation of $n^2$ is greater than or equal to sum of digits in decimal representation of $n$.

How many GRT numbers are there ?

Comment: Please fix the question and please **never** type something like `$2. Sum \ of \ digits \ in \ decimal \ representation \ of \  n^2 \ is \ greater \ than \ or \ equal \ to \ sum \ of \ digits \ in \ decimal \ representation \ of \ n.$` again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't prove it absolutely, but for any $m$ there must be infinitely many.  Any large $n$ that is $\equiv 1 \bmod m$ will have a square with lots more digits than $n$ has, so the sum of digits of the square will be larger.